# C++ stringstream splitting

Tags: c++, vector, split, stringstream

I have been combing through this site and many others for days, here is the problem I'm having. I have a string that I am from a `char*` that I need to parse, 90% of the time it parses just fine, but on certain strings I get garbage characters and it doesn't split as expected. You can see an example in the img: [Garbage Characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP5wH.jpg)

here is the code I am using (I have tried many other alternatives to this as well, this is the only one that came close)

```
bool __stdcall ChatLogger::HandleNewChatLine( short sMode, char* szText )
{
    ofstream chatlog;
    ofstream chatparsed;

    if(sMode == 660)
    {
        string data = szText;

        chatparsed.open("D:\\chatlog_parsed.txt", ios_base::app );
        chatparsed << data << '\n' << '\n';
        chatparsed.close();

        string buf; // Have a buffer string
        stringstream ss(data); // Insert the string into a stream

        vector<string> tokens; // Create vector to hold our words

        while (ss >> buf)
        {
            tokens.push_back(buf);
        }

        chatparsed.open("D:\\chatlog_parsed.txt", ios_base::app );

        for(size_t i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
        {
            chatparsed << "array pos: " << i << "    " << tokens[i] << '\n';
        }
        chatparsed.close();
    }

    chatlog.open("D:\\chatlog.txt", ios_base::app );
    chatlog << "Line ID: " << sMode << "    " << "Text: " << szText << '\n';
    chatlog.close();

    return false;
}
```

Ultimately there should only be a word per line and if at all possible I really need to eliminate the garbage chars either be deleting them from the individual strings in the vector or ideally before. Perhaps some way to iterate through the `std::stringstream` before putting it in the vector and deleting the garbage characters or converting them to spaces somehow.

Comment: open `chatlog_parsed` twice?

Comment: The linked image shows a few non-alphanumeric characters and a few that might look like whitespace, but certainly not enough to indicate there is something wrong with your code. These characters are part of the string that gets passed to `ChatLogger::HandleNewChatLine`. If you need to eliminate them, you will have to do that manually, with an additional pass over the string.

Comment: Well if I could somehow split the lines where they occur I wouldn't need to eliminate them but that's what I'm having trouble with. I would be up for either though either eliminating them or just splitting on those characters, any ideas?

Comment: you re using input argument as char* that's probably reason for garbage  characters try string sztext